# Is it possible/advisable to seed Users/Roles using the EFCore 2.1 Data Seeding system?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

As of EFCore 2.1 it's possible to seed data using the DbContext OnModelCreating method.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding

However user/role creation is usually handled by a UserManager/RoleManager.

Now, I can manually create a Role or User - but for example in the case of a User I need to hash the password myself (and I don't know what hashing method is used by the UserManager without digging into the source)

Is there any way around this? Or should I stick with having a static seeding method that runs on startup as in previous versions of Entity Framework Core?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the `OnModelCreating` method with the `HasData` method you can do it like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        ApplicationUser appUser = new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = "tester",
            Email = "tester@test.com",
            NormalizedEmail = "tester@test.com".ToUpper(),
            NormalizedUserName = "tester".ToUpper(),
            TwoFactorEnabled = false,
            EmailConfirmed = true,
            PhoneNumber = "123456789",
            PhoneNumberConfirmed = false
        };

        PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> ph = new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>();
        appUser.PasswordHash = ph.HashPassword(appUser, "Your-PW1");

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(
            new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin", NormalizedName = "ADMIN" },
            new IdentityRole { Name = "User", NormalizedName = "USER"}
        );
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasData(
            appUser
        );
    }
```

If you create the user outside the `HasData` method you can use the `PasswordHasher`.
It will hash the password for you. Then just put the created user into `HasData` instead of creating a new one there. 
I don't know if that's better than the seeding on startup, but its one way to do it.

Comment: Thats indeed better than `seeding on startup` as Microsoft says `The seeding code should not be part of the normal app execution`, but they also say `.HasData()` should not be used for `Data that requires calls to external API, such as ASP.NET Core Identity roles and users creation` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#model-seed-data